# Outlined button with white background

Tags: swiftui, swift5

How can I create an button like this In SwiftUI?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you need to make the button the same width as a screen then add some paddings.

```
  var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}) {
          Text("Text")
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(10)
          }
          .border(Color.gray, width: 1, cornerRadius: 5)
          .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20)
      }
```

Comment: How can I add a background color? If I use .background(Color.blue) it doesn't clip, I tried .clipped already it didn't work.

Comment: Use  `.cornerRadius(5)` modifier before padding

Answer (score 0):

To add a border to any view simply add this modifier with the desired arguments:

```
.border(Color.black, width: 1, cornerRadius: 2)
```

Sizing of the button itself can be done through padding or manually setting its frame.